# How can I change the logo that comes up when I boot my laptop (before grub)

Tags: boot

My manufacturer's logo, Lenovo, comes up as soon I press the power button. It is in the very first stages of boot, before the GRUB2 screen.

I suspect it is stored in the BIOS but I have no idea where to find the image file.

I just want to know where that image is kept so I can edit it.

I am on a Lenovo U310 running many Linux distros including Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. This is impossible, unless you have extreme levels of intelligence of your BIOS and your computer, architecture, everything.

Just forget about changing it, you can't unless you make your own BIOS, which  can be very dangerous and break your computr.